# ISA Inheritance with different primary keys in ER Diagram

Tags: entity-relationship

I want to draw an ER diagram for a company where there are engineers and architects as workers. I created three entites and I want to create an ISA inheritance from engineers to workers. All the workers have a unique worker_id. All the engineers also have a unique engineer_id. How can I show that each engineer has both unique worker_id and engineer_id with using ISA inheritance?

Comment: Why do the engineers (and architects) have a new separate unique id? Why not use the already existing worker_id?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the ER diagram you have and show the problem you have with adding the `worker_id` and `engineer_id` attributes.